# all ldap users are created on ubuntu client

Tags: openldap

We configured our LDAP on our Ubuntu 14.04 desktop's.
When we login with the ldap user we can see all other users which are in LDAP... 
This was not what we needed. How can we disable this.

Kr,

Joeri

Comment: What do you mean by "we can see all other users"?

Comment: If you press the shutdown button in the right corner all the existing users in ldap our displayed under the lock / switch account tab.